# Android searchview hide keyboard but no losing focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've a PDA with Android and barcode scanner integrated. I would to hide always keyboard to use barcode scanner. I've a `searchview` with an editetext field to search into my products through my app. I need to close keyboard but I haven't losing focus on search field. There is any way to this feature?

I'm using searchView.clearFocus() but I lose focus

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())); searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Post us some of your code regarding the keybord / searchview / focus...

Comment: OMG edit your question please, do not post code as comment, it's unreadable. EDIT: well I did

Comment: Hey Claudio, I'm having the same issue, I'm trying to hide the softkeyboard but keeping the blinking cursor, did the accepted answer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This method generally works. I would be very surprised if this would lose the focus, it simply gets the current focus.

Comment: Hey Claudio, I'm having the same issue, I'm trying to hide the softkeyboard but keeping the blinking cursor, did the accepted answer work?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your    **Manifest.xml:**

```
<your_activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
</your_activity>
```